# Using Bundle to update textview from one fragment to another fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I followed the code examples on using bundle to send data from one fragment to another fragment, but my textview where I want to display the bundle value containing a string is not showing the stored value.

The string value is getting the phone name contact which the user has click on from the listview, which the toast line below showing that it has successfully got the name picked.

I've rewritten the code to send the string value to the fragment multiple times following the examples, but I am having no luck.

**SelectModemFragment**

```
 // Set the ListViews OnItemClick Listener
            display_contacts1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    String namedisplay = arrayAdapter.getItem(position); //<<<<<<<<<< this gets the phone name

                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), namedisplay + " Selected for Communication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Using bundle to send data
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(namedisplay, "namevalue");

                    // Begin transaction to command window
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    CommandsFragment modemFragment = new CommandsFragment();
                    modemFragment.setArguments(bundle); // Data to be send to commands fragment
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, modemFragment);
                    transaction.commit();

                    //modemView.setText(namedisplay);
                }
            });
```

**CommandsFragment**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_commands_view, container, false);

        modemView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.modem_view);

        if (display_contacts.isEmpty())
        {
            number = null;

            // No contacts selected from the Add Modem listview
            modemView.setText("No contact selected");
        }
        else
        {
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            modemView.setText(String.valueOf(bundle.getString("namevalue")));
        }

        return view;
}
```

Comment: Try this  `bundle.putString("namevalue",namedisplay);`

Comment: Change this `bundle.getString("namevalue")` to `bundle.getString(namedisplay)`. `namedisplay` - should be actual name of key.

Answer (score 1):

this line is your problem:

```
bundle.putString(namedisplay, "namevalue");
```

it should be

```
bundle.putString("namevalue", namedisplay);
```

first put key, then value.

Comment: But all the other lines are ok?

Comment: from what you pasted seems so. Bundle is a map, and works as a map - you store values based on key. You must always put key first, and value second. Your code shows that you put value as a key, and that is why, when you look map for 'namevalue' it does not return a string, as there is no key like that in map

Comment: I did the update where I change the line to bundle.putString("namevalue", namedisplay); but it still didn't work